# 'Cumulative' bar chart in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot 5 histograms in one plot. To make this readable, I have thought of using a 'cumulative' (not sure whether this is the right term) bar chart, but couldn't find an easy implementation in MATLAB. Is there one ?

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
a=1:5
b=5:-1:1
```

when I try a normal bar chart, it would look like this:

```
bar([a ;b]')
```

[image]

and what I want is this (excuse hasty image editing):
[image]

I cannot achieve this with using 'bar' twice with 'hold on', since one of the bar charts will cover the other one.

ps: if there are better ways of plotting multiple histograms on the plot, except using density curves, please feel free to advise :)

Comment: You basically want to plot the bars on top of each other, but let the larger bars stand out.  Consult the duplicate.

Comment: as noted, the duplicate case is simpler, as the values there are always ordered.  Here I cannot simply plot the bars on top of each other as the ones which I plot later will cover the ones which I plot earlier, if their values are higher. In this sense the answer provided below is a solution for the case with 2 arrays, but in my actual problem I have five, which would make this way rather complicated I think.

Comment: @rayryeng you may want to take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315794/3764814).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks. I'll reopen the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you might be looking for :

```
bar([a ;b]', 'stacked')
```

=== EDIT 1 ===

Looking more closely at your drawing, you might also be looking for a less conventional "stacking" which you can achieve by superimposing both bars like so :

```
a=(1:5)';
b=(5:-1:1)';
c = a;
c(b<=a)=nan;
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
bar([a,b]);
subplot(1,2,2);
hold on;
bar(a,'b');
bar(b,'r');
bar(c,'b');
hold off
```

This yields the following figure, which is similar to yours:
[image]

=== END OF EDIT 1 ===

=== EDIT 2 ===

here is an implementation of what i was suggesting in my comments to extend that idea to an arbitrary number of series. basically, each layer (from tallest to smallest) is painted (using patch) in a loop. Although this is not a Matlab Bar chart anymore (which, to my knowledge, cannot solve your problem due to the fact that independent horizontal bars for a given serie cannot be accessed through uistack), the resulting figure fits the description you gave.

```
function testBarOverlay()
    % data initialization
    nbSeries = 8;
    nbBars = 5;
    xt = 1:nbBars;
    data = rand( nbBars, nbSeries );

    %draw (then erase) figure and get the characteristics of Matlab bars (axis, colors...)
    figure;
    h = bar( data( :, 1 ) );
    width = get( h, 'barWidth' );
    delete( h );

    % sort in order to start painting the tallest bars
    [ sdata, idx ] = sort( data, 2 );

    % get the vertices of the different "bars", drawn as polygons
    x = [ kron( xt, [1;1] ) - width / 2; kron( xt, [1;1] ) + width / 2 ];

    % paint each layer, starting with the 'tallest' ones first
    for i = nbSeries : -1 : 1
        y = [ zeros( nbBars, 1 ), sdata( :, i ), sdata( :, i ), zeros( nbBars, 1 ) ]';
        p = patch( x, y, 'b' );
        set( p, 'FaceColor', 'Flat', 'CData', idx( :, i )' );
    end
end
```

[image]

=== END OF EDIT 2 ===

Comment: Not exactly, the 'stacked' option would stack them (so in the barchart, the height of all the bars would be 6 in my example). whereas I am looking for a cumulative option.

Comment: just saw your comment after posting my edit. does my edit answer your question perhaps ?

Comment: basically, the "front" color is always the one with the lowest value in this case.

Comment: @rayryeng, i don't agree that this is a duplicate, at least not of the answer you provided : in the answer you provided the matrix was ordered from smallest to biggest, which makes superimposing a bit less tricky. in the OP's case, one way of circumventing this is by adding a third conditional layer, which is what I've proposed.

Comment: thanks, the edit actually does provide a solution for the case with 2 arrays, but in my actual problem I have five, which would make this method rather complicated I think...

Comment: Well, basically adding an arbitrary number of series is not really a problem since the methodology above can be used, although it will be messy. Unfortunately, bars in a bar-chart cannot be accessed independently to move them from one layer to another, which means that if you move the first "blue" bar to the front they all move to the front. That is why I had to resort to creating a new series with NaNs when no bar should be drawn. An alternative avenue, if you are ready to disregard some of the advantages of using a pre-made bar-chart, could be to recreate your own (e.g. patch, fill)

Comment: I have edited the answer to give you an example implementation for an arbitrary number of series using the second method suggested (patch). Both methods work, it's just a matter of how you will implement them from here. Best, Tepp.

Comment: Thanks, this works very well, with the minor change: `xt = 1:nbBars;` instead of `xt = get( gca, 'XTick' );`. Will edit this in your code.

Comment: my edit was rejected, so you might want to edit this yourself (using the original code results in error, when the number of the ticks is less than the number of the bars, which is often the case when using higher number of bars)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out about that last bug, I have edited the answer accordingly.